# C++/CLI: Use LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress with an exe

Tags: winapi, c++-cli, exe, loadlibrary

Up until now, I had some sort of plugin mechanism in which I loaded dlls using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to create a concrete object and return a common interface. This worked fine until I decided that one of the dlls should be an exe.

[LoadLibrary's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that it can be used for exe's as well, so I gave it a shot. The exe gets loaded without errors, as GetProcAddress. But when I try to call my concrete object's constructor, I get an access violation.

I thought this would happen because loading an exe does not load all the dlls it uses. So I tried loading them using LoadLibrary, but I got the same error.
Any advice on this?

Here's my code (mixed C++/CLI):

```
Interface* MCFactory::LoadInstanceFromAssembly( String ^ concreteAssemblyName, String ^ param ){
    string fullPathToAssembly = "";
    fullPathToAssembly += FileSystem::GetPathToProgramDirectory();
    fullPathToAssembly += "\\" + marshal_as<string>(concreteAssemblyName);

    MODULE hDLL = AssemblyLoader::GetInstance().LoadAssembly( fullPathToAssembly ); 

    Interface* pObject = NULL;
    if (hDLL != NULL){
        t_pCreateInstanceFunction pCreateInstanceFunction =
            (t_pCreateInstanceFunction) ::GetProcAddress (hDLL, CREATE_INSTANCE_FUNCTION_NAME.c_str());

        if ( pCreateInstanceFunction != NULL ){
            //Yes, this assembly exposes the function we need
            //Invoke the function to create the object
            pObject = (*pCreateInstanceFunction)( marshal_as<string>(param) );              
        }
    }           
    return pObject;
}
```

(AssemblyLoader::GetInstance().LoadAssembly is just a wrapper for ::LoadLibrary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1045674/Load-EXE-as-DLL-Mission-Possible

The idea is to patch the IAT, then call the CRT. Of course, the EXE must be relocatable, and by default (ASLR) it is.

Comment: Of course, that method requires some very invasive changes to the EXE.  It may work in specific scenarios, but not for the general case.

Comment: Everything I say in that article is not undocumented. Therefore it will work as long as the conditions remain the same (i.e. rellocations existing, CRT called, IAT patched).

Comment: Huh?  Every trick you are using is making undocumented assumptions.  Show me one official Microsoft document that says it's ok to call `WinMainCRTStartup` in a second module (Important observation: every time `WinMainCRTStartup` calls `GetModuleHandle(0)`, it doesn't get a handle to the module it is initializing, but the main module of the process.  All manner of resources won't be found correctly, including manifests.)  And that's just the beginning.

Comment: You do have a point, but calling the CRT is not necessary. It's only meant to initialize global variables - if you need them.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` on the main executable for your process, this allows dynamic exports in the reverse direction (.exe to .dll).

You cannot load a second .exe into your process memory space, except for access to resources/data, because .exe code is not relocatable.  (Pure MSIL .exe files are an exception, because there is no code in the file, it's all generated by the JIT.)

Basically, `LoadLibrary` on a .exe is useful only when

- The .exe is the main process exe, in which case you might as well use `GetModuleHandle`

  or
- The `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag is used

Comment: Does having ASLR enabled make it possible to load multiple .exes into a single process?

Comment: @ildjarn: You mean an ASLR-compatibility compiler option, not the OS setting?  I don't think so.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Just curious.

Comment: @ildjarn: Perhaps these are relevant: [`/FIXED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w368ysh2.aspx) [`/DYNAMICBASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887.aspx)

Comment: @ildjarn: And [this thread](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=136276) seems to indicate that an executable, even ASLR-capable, cannot be loaded as code.

Comment: It is possible. Check my answer's link.