# C++ Code Injection crashes injected application

Tags: c++, c, firefox, code-injection, dll-injection

I'm trying to inject a simple executable into another executable that I made, unfortunately, whenever I inject the code into the executable, it says 'simpleinjected.exe has stopped working' then it closes. I'm using `CreateRemoteThread` to inject the code. This is what I have done so far.

**Injector.exe**     // the file that's injecting the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define procId 2844
#define executable "executable.exe"    // located in same directory

int main()
{
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, procId);
    LPVOID allocated = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, strlen(executable), MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)allocated, executable, strlen(executable), NULL);
    LPVOID libaddr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)libaddr, NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hProc);
    return 0;
}
```

**Simpleinjected.exe**    // the file being injected

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

**executable.exe**    // the executable being injected into simpleinjected

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Injected successfully", "Code Injection", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

The message is not displaying and `simpleinjected.exe` crashes. The crash shows that the code was inserted but I don't understand why it's crashing.

When using DLL and the same technique above, the dll executes in the 'simpleinjected.exe' but doesn't work when injected into Firefox. The dll code is below. It executes in the custom application but not Firefox even though it's injected successfully.

**dllinject.dll**

```
#include <windows.h>

int message(const char *msg)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, msg, "Message from Dll", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI DLLMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD ulReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch(ulReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            message("process attach");
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            message("thread attach");
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            message("process detach");
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            message("thread detach");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it hard enough to inject a **DLL** into someone else process, much less another *executable*?

Comment: so it's not possible?

Comment: If you're asking whether the [CreateRemoteThread/LoadLibrary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces#section_2) technique will work with a EXE rather than a DLL, [**I doubt it**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283482/c-cli-use-loadlibrary-getprocaddress-with-an-exe), but I've never tried. I can tell you your `VirtualAlloc` region isn't large enough, as `strlen(executable)` doesn't include space for your terminator char (which also needs to be written, btw). best of luck with this, btw.

Comment: so how am i to inject code into another process then?

Comment: Write a DLL and follow any of the how-to guides available on the web to do precisely that.

Comment: using dll, i can do it but it doesn't work for injecting into Firefox..let me edit the question to show when done with dll..

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but *why* are you seeking to inject code into another process (that presumably does not want to the code since it's not looking for it in a dynamic library)? 
What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: i'm interested in dll injection, not trying to solve any problem, just satisfying me curiosity.

Comment: Have you considered that Firefox apparently has some sort of protection against the stuff you are trying to do? Because execution of mallicious code is something which most apps are being protected against. Web browsers especially.

Comment: There's some nice info on what you want to do here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces
I suspect you'll find that recent versions of windows will require user intervention to allow the calls to complete (a process is attempting to... do you wish to allow this?).

Comment: @HighPredator, i didn't know that cos it was simply injecting in the app i made.

Comment: @RichardHodges, i've read that article and unfortunately it uses inline assembly which i'm not so good at

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest. Injecting code into another process is probably the most complex thing you can try with an operating system. It requires an understanding of the processor and OS architecture.

Comment: I also used an injector from the internet and the dll injects successfully and executes.

Answer (score 1):

modified code of Simpleinjected.exe as these below. and then try inject dllinject.dll to Simpleinjected.exe again.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   while(true)
   {
      printf("Hello");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

you should modify the defines below as same as Simpleinjected.exe.

```
#define procId 2844 //process id of Simpleinjected.exe
#define executable "dllinject.dll"    // located in same directory
```

Comment: it is possible to inject in the simpleinjected.exe, it works but it doesn't inject in firefox.

Comment: the dependency injection tag of the question is wrong. The question is about injecting into EXE.