# Dll not being loaded in Firefox but loads in custom application

Tags: c++, c, firefox, dll-injection

I posted a recent question on SO about [code injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117920/c-code-injection-crashes-injected-application), this one is similar but not the same. I am injecting dll into Firefox, it injects successfully but the code in the DLL doesn't run. If i inject the same code into a custom application, it works. Why might that be. This is the code that I'm using.

**Injector.exe**     // the file that's injecting the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define procId 2844
#define dllname "dllinject.dll"    // located in same directory

int main()
{
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, procId);
    LPVOID allocated = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, strlen(dllname), MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)allocated, dllname, strlen(dllname), NULL);
    LPVOID libaddr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)libaddr, NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hProc);
    return 0;
}
```

**Simpleinjected.exe**    // the file being injected

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

**dllinject.dll**

```
#include <windows.h>

int message(const char *msg)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, msg, "Message from Dll", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI DLLMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD ulReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch(ulReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            message("process attach");
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            message("thread attach");
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            message("process detach");
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            message("thread detach");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It works when injected into `simpleinjected.exe` but when injected in Firefox, nothing happens even though the dll is injected successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your observations. I was able to inject dllinject.dll into other processes (also firefox) but I've never seen a message box.

After a bit of digging I found that your `DLLMain` is spelled wrong. Change it into `DllMain` and you'll see message boxes in Firefox.

By the way: You propably want to change `MessageBox` into `MessageBeep` since FireFox creates/destroys a lot of threads... (this is annoying even for a quick test!)